# I want to be able to use the stripe connect with meteor

Tags: meteor, stripe-connect

Does any one have sample code or are aware of tutorials that allow me to use stripe connect with meteor.

Comment: https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/payments-with-stripe-checkout/

Comment: I am looking to use the "connect" feature for a marketplace (https://stripe.com/connect), any guides on that?